# Proving the Alternating Series Test using Cauchy Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

I'm self-studying analysis using Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbott, and ran into proving the Alternating Series Test.

**Theorem 2.7.7. (Alternating Series Test).**

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence satisfying,

(i) $a_n \geq a_{n+1}$ for all n $\in \mathbb{N}$ and

(ii) $(a_n)\rightarrow0$. Then, the alternating series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n+1}a_n}$ converges.

**Proof**

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given. Since $(a_n) \rightarrow 0$, there exists $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that whenever $n \geq N$ it follows that $|a_n|<\epsilon$.

Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence of partial sums of the alternating series so that $s_n = a_1 - a_2 + a_3 -...\pm a_n$. Consider $|s_n - s_m|$ where $n>m\geq N$ and $n=m+1$. Then, $|s_n - s_m| = |\pm a_n| < \epsilon$. Thus, $(s_n)$ is a Cauchy Sequence and since every Cauchy Sequence is convergent the alternating series converges. $\square$

This was my first attempt, but felt like there was something wrong with the proof. I would appreciate any help/feedback of the proof!

Comment: if $|s_n-s_{n+1}|<\varepsilon$ It doesn't mean the sequence is cauchy. For example, consider the harmonic series. You need to prove an upper bound for any $n > m$.

Comment: You also need to use the fact the helper sequence $a_n$ is decreasing.

Comment: A good starting point would be to consider the partial sums as two separate subsequences. Hint: show that both subsequences converge to the same, what does this say about the whole sum's limit/convergence?